# Using Vue 2 libraries on a Vue 3 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Is there a way I can use a library made with vue 2 on my vue 3 project?

there is a package that I made using vue 2 and I want to import it on my vue 3 project, and it doesn't seem to work.
It gives the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uhi1.png).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"` only works with (maximum) `Vue 2.6.11`

`Vue 3` works with `"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.4"`

Look this way.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you know maybe how can I Fix this error?
I removed the node_modules, installed vue 3 and compiler-sfc both to the latest version, and removed vue-template-compiler from the package.json, but I still seems to get the same error.

Comment: I think you need to remake the library to Vue3

Comment: I had to redo https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-countdown-clock from Vue2 to https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-clock-countdown from Vue3